# Admob Android: findViewById not resolved

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I can't build my project because findViewById is not resolved. What could be wrong? Could it be because I left out some Admob code in other files? How can I make Admob work. I tried cleaning my code and clearing the cache. What could be the problem?

Here's my code in AndroidApplication.java:

```
    package io.enormous.avocardo;

    import android.app.Application;
    import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
    import io.enormous.avocardo.common.analytics.AnswersTracker;
    import io.enormous.avocardo.common.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker;
    import io.enormous.avocardo.common.di.ApplicationComponent;
    import io.enormous.avocardo.common.di.ApplicationModule;
    import io.enormous.avocardo.common.di.DaggerApplicationComponent;
    import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;
    import timber.log.Timber;
    import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

    public class AndroidApplication extends Application {

    private Mode mode;
    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    checkTestMode();
    this.initializeInjector();

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-7014730672857176~3011130441");

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
```

Comment: Show the activity code

Answer (score 1):

`Application` doesn't have View, so you can't find any view there. You should do it in activity or fragment.